# How can I split a string with occurrence of "users/" from a URL?

Tags: ios, swift

I Am using this method, this is my URL "https://www.youtube.com/user/myYoutubeChennal". and i want to get "myYoutubeChennal" from this.

```
func splitVideoUrl(videoUrl:String) -> String {

    //let token = videoUrl.split(separator: "user/")
    let ttstr:String = " https://www.youtube.com/user/myYoutubeChennal"
    if let range = ttstr.range(of: "user/") {
        let firstPart = String(describing: ttstr.startIndex..<range.lowerBound)
        print(firstPart) // print Hello
        return firstPart
    }
    return ""
}
```

Comment: Please add more detail are you want?

Comment: Thuan Nguyen Please check now i have edited it.

Comment: This is a URL and you want to get a component from it... I’d suggest starting with the class `URLComponents` And stop treating this like a string.

Comment: Ok i got it. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: My answers is same with miOS, please refer it. Sorry, I reply late.

Comment: Ok No Problem @Thuan Nguyen you helped thats enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the last component of URL using following code

```
let url = URL(string:"https://www.youtube.com/user/myYoutubeChennal")
let lastComponent = url?.lastPathComponent
```

Comment: My pleasure you helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the desired string is always the path component after `user` split the string by slashes, get the index of `user` and then the item `index + 1`

```
let string = "https://www.youtube.com/user/myYoutubeChennal"
let components = string.components(separatedBy: "/")
if let index = components.index(of: "user"), index < components.count - 1 {
    let user = components[index + 1]
} else {
   print("user not found")
}
```